# How can I read the contents of a file and store in an array c program?

Tags: c

Suppose the .txt file contains numbers such as :
52
53
54

How can I store these numbers which are to be read from the file into an array of some order?

Comment: You need `fopen` and `fscanf`. Your C textbook should contain a chapter that deals with these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");

    int numberArray[3];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        fscanf(myFile, "%d", &numberArray[i]);
    }
    // Do more stuff with numberArray
}
```

Comment: However I was wondering like is it possible to enclose the file opening and writing the contents to the array inside from a structure and calling it in the main?

Answer (score 1):

```
int array[3];
...
fscanf(file, "%d %d %d", array, array+1, array+2);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your **.txt file** and **C program** have to be in same directory.
2. Read from the file using file pointer **(FILE***) and save to it in a **string**.
3. Now get number from the **string** and store these numbers in an **array**.
4. Sort the **array**.